# pop up is not closing in angular 6

Tags: angular

Here is my Parent element html :

```
<fme-header-icon title="Manage" iconName="class" (click)="triggerPopup(true)">
  <fme-pop-up-panel *ngIf="showPopUpManage" (onCloseEvent)='popUpCloseEvent($event)'></fme-pop-up-panel>
</fme-header-icon>
```

if the user clicks on Header icon it will load a pop-up window. Now when the user clicks out of the pop-up window then it will close. 
For that, I created an even through @Hostlistener in the pop-up panel(child element) which will detect the click event if it occurs outside the child element. 
Now this will be thrown to the parent element by event emitter.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'fme-pop-up-panel',
  templateUrl: './pop-up-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pop-up-panel.component.scss']
})
export class PopUpPanelComponent implements OnInit {
  popUpClose: boolean;
  @Output() onCloseEvent: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Input() title: string;
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log(event.target);

    } else {
      this.popUpClose = true; // if click outside it will set to true
      this.onOutsideClick();

    }
  }

  constructor(private _eref: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onOutsideClick() {
    this.onCloseEvent.emit(this.popUpClose);
  }
}
```

in parent element i was tring to do this.

```
showPopUpManage:boolean= false;
popUpCloseEvent(event: boolean) {
    this.showPopUpManage = !event; // if click outsite set to false & close the pop-up
    console.log("Hi55", this.showPopUpManage, this.popUpclose);
  }

triggerPopupManage(status: boolean) {
    this.showPopUpManage = status;
    console.log("Hi55", this.showPopUpManage, this.popUpclose);

  }
```

But its not working. can you tell me how to close this pop up?

Comment: Try to console log the HostListener in the child, does it works? I assume its not because of ngZone detection. let me know.

Comment: what you mean,sorry i do not get it. if u want to know whether it's sending the event while it's clicked from outside, then ya its working. @dAxx_

Comment: so in popUpCloseEvent() you are logging the right boolean value? but its still does not close ?

Comment: ya.. it has right value. but while user click on menu  both the function popUpCloseEvent and triggerPopupManage runs . that so confusing. no idea why its happening @ dAxx_

Comment: I see, so its invoke the click on both components, did you try to add event.stopPropagation(); on the HostListener?

Comment: No I did not try this. if i try to stop propagate how will that work? like when user click outside the popup will that send back to the parent if I use the stopPropagation() method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176075/discussion-between-kazi-and-daxx).

Comment: No, It should stop propagate to the father, add it in the end of the HostListener function and tell me if it works, or at least now you get log only once and not once.

Comment: its working now. thanks man. thanks a lot. its bcz of stopPropagation()

Comment: I've submitted the answer so it may help others. please accect if it helps you! good luck man !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your click event invoked twice, First by the child then by the parent.

 
So, every time the value stays the same.
 
You have to stop the propagation of the event, so it will stop at child level.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
clickout(event) {
  if (this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
    console.log(event.target);

  } else {
    this.popUpClose = true; // if click outside it will set to true
    this.onOutsideClick();

  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: hi there is a problem. its not working if you put stopPropagation in the child element. rather you need to add it in the parent. can you tell me the reason plz @dAxx_